# Subprocess function python: Use in automation

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I am trying to run this command in the terminal using Python:

> ./Pascal --set=settings/1_settings.txt --runpathway=on
>   --genescoring=sum --pval=1_snp_values.txt.gz

I need to run this script 180 times using a different pval everytime. Hence, automating it via Python saves me a lot of time.

Currently I have a Python subprocess like this:

> subprocess.call("./Pascal --set=settings/1_settings.txt
>   --runpathway=on --genescoring=sum --pval=1_snp_values.txt.gz")

Although, I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_automation.py", line 4, in <module>
    subprocess.call("./Pascal --set=settings/1_settings.txt --runpathway=on --genescoring=sum --pval=1_snp_values.txt.gz")
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
```

The problem is when I execute the exact same command in terminal (outside of the Python code) it works fine. Am I using the syntax incorrectly?

Comment: can you try `shell=True` (not the best solution, that said!) ? what is your `Pascal` command? a script? an executable?

Comment: also: is `Pascal` in the correct directory when you're running your script?

Comment: Pascal is an executable. I got it working using your solution but since os.system is depreciated could you update your answer to work with subprocess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Using [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system)...

You could try using this to run your terminal command like so:

```
import os
os.system("./Pascal --set=settings/1_settings.txt --runpathway=on --genescoring=sum --pval=1_snp_values.txt.gz")
```

And if this works, it is simple to execute in a `for-loop` to get it to run `180` times:

```
import os
for _ in range(180):
    os.system("./Pascal --set=settings/1_settings.txt --runpathway=on --genescoring=sum --pval=1_snp_values.txt.gz")
```

Additionally, if `Pascal` is in the same directory that you are running your script then the path of `./` is not necessary as by default, it will search the current working directory. So you can change it to just `Pascal --set-settings...`

## Using [`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call)...

Personally, I think using `os.system` is a cleaner solution, however you can use `subprocess.call` to do the same thing in one of two ways, either:

call `Pascal` and the other arguments separately from a `list` like:

```
import subprocess as s
s.call(['./Pascal', '--set=settings/1_settings.txt', '--runpathway=on', '--genescoring=sum', '--pval=1_snp_values.txt.gz'])
```

or just set `shell` to `true` and pass in the full line as a string like:

```
import subprocess as s
s.call('./Pascal --set=settings/1_settings.txt --runpathway=on --genescoring=sum --pval=1_snp_values.txt.gz', shell=True)
```

Hope this works for you!

Comment: `os.system` is deprecated and using `subprocess.call` is much better. This answer doesn't improve OP's situation.

Comment: os.system worked perfectly, subprocess still doesn't work. Can you update the answer to use subprocess.call?

Comment: You assumed wrong. But since you solved OP problem have my +1

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks for helping me out because I haven't got much rep yet so that means a lot :)

Comment: I could not leave an ok answer, accepted, with a negative score

Comment: I ended up putting the queries into an array and I call them using this "subprocess.call(queries[i], shell=True)"